Show third party calling or SMS app in the "Connected Apps" list of the android default contact app. Like how Whatsapp ,Teligram...etc are showing
Ours is android calling and SMS app. Need our app to be shown option in the "Connected Apps" list of the android's default contact app like Whatsapp, Truecaller and Teligram etc. As shown in the image.
tried with ContentProvider and SyncAdapter. But couldn't to achieve.
Please help me if you have any idea on this. Thank you in advance
        // Tried with ContentProvider and SyncAdapter
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>



Launch WhatsApp based on your highlighted area. Then, examine Logcat to see what Intent was used. From there, you can see what might be different between that and your <intent-filter>. My guess is that you need a different category, but that is just a guess.

Thank you @CommonsWare. In the logcat got this
ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       I  START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/395 typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile pkg=com.whatsapp cmp=com.whatsapp/.accountsync.ProfileActivity (has extras)} from uid 10097

OK, so that Intent is an explicit Intent, with a specific component (cmp=com.whatsapp/.accountsync.ProfileActivity). So, that part didn't help. However, it is interesting that the Intent uses a contact Uri (content://com.android.contacts/data/395) and a custom contact MIME type (vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile). My guess is that your solution lies somewhere in there, but I do not know what it would be.
